# Turn off light bouncing for one view layer only

Tags: rendering, viewlayers

I'd like one of my passes ( view layers) to have the Total set to 0 in the Light paths>Max Bounces of the Render properties. (cycles renderer)

How can I over ride this setting for just one view layer?

Many thanks.

Comment: New Scene > Linked Copy ... like that you can control bounces independently and mix View Layers in Compositor (that you would have to anyway) ... or probably better if you can illustrate by image (mockup) with desired result ...  reason for such thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share any production images for confidentiality reasons. Basicly we've been tasked with animating some "Cartoony" (hand drawn) looking characters into a live action plate. The idea is to develope a toon shaded version of the characters, (Complete with toony textures) to render in one view layer, and more realistic material version ( complete with sub surface and bounced light to match the plate) in another view layer and fine tune the "toonyness" of the final result by combining the two in comp.

Comment: Nobody is asking you to share confidential data ... to illustrate your situation you can find reference on internet or create some mockup by you. Simple ball (as character) visualised or structured in desired result could be enough with some description. My comment is answering given question, but maybe can be handled by another way ... like by shader, but it depends how you want to get toon effect and how comp is done ... for that your file and reference of result is the fastest way to help you. Please take a few minutes to extend your Q to avoid our guessing. Thanks

Comment: You've already answered the question. The linked scene allows me to switch off the bounce and acts like the over ride I need. thanks

Comment: If this solution fits to you than OK :) Good luck with your project.